# With Bootstrap datetimepicker: How can I hide the time if it is not selected?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker

I used this tutorial to implement datetimepicker [datetimepicker bootstrap](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

However I don't want the time is displayed if it is not selected

I tried add the format option as `"DD-MM-YYYY"` however with this option, the user can't select time.

This is my code:

```js
$(function() {
    $('#datetimepicker6').datetimepicker({
        useCurrent:'year',
        locale: 'fr'
    });
    $('#datetimepicker7').datetimepicker({
        useCurrent: false, //Important! See issue #1075
        locale: 'fr'
    });
    $("#datetimepicker6").on("dp.change", function(e) {
        $('#datetimepicker7')
            .data("DateTimePicker")
            .minDate(e.date);
    });
    $("#datetimepicker7").on("dp.change", function(e) {
        $('#datetimepicker6')
            .data("DateTimePicker")
            .maxDate(e.date);
    });
});
```

any help?
thanks

Comment: Are you aware of this [datepicker](https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) only control? Why not use it if you don't need the time component?

Comment: When the user  select a date and time, it will be displayed in the input field what I need exactly is  if he select  only the  date so only the date will be displayed in the input field
with my code if the user select only date it show like this 4/14/2016 00:00